# Website does not work properly on android

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a portfolio website, on the portfolio page it does this weird thing on android, only android not IOS. my website is  the problem happens on the other pages work normally on android except the portfolio page. this is the problem[![this is what it looks like on android][1]][1]  [![this is what it is supposed to look like][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set content width

```
width: max-content;
```

Comment: Lol Sorry, I just saw what you meant, it was very late here, I was unable to see it properly.